# How to create dynamic div and add data into it from different elements in other xhtml?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In below code I want to add the div dynamically under div tag with id="includedContent". And also load data using number of ids.So instead of having a hardcoded Id(123) to load method i want to make it accept Array of ids and displqay the data in the dynamically created tag???

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function vikas(){
        var i=0;
        $(function(){
            $("#includedContent").load("b.xhtml #123");
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" style="width:80px; height:40px;" onclick="vikas()">Click</button>
    <div id="includedContent" >vikas<img click="vikas()" src="www.google.com" alt=""></img><br/></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a perfect case for using a templating engine like MustacheJS http://mustache.github.io/

It allows you to create a template into a variable and then "throw" a JSON-Object onto a new instance of an mustacheJS and it will replace some placeholders you are defining in the template (they'll look like this:{{variable}}). You can find easy follow examples on their website.

I hope i could help.

Comment: Please share your attempts by showing what you tried to accomplish using it. I can assist you to solve the issues.

Comment: do you need to do it completely without any additional framework?